# How to compute $E \left[ e^{-\|{\bf X}\|^2} \right]$ where ${\bf X}$ is Gaussian with a covariance matrix ${\bf K}$

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let ${\bf X}$ be a Gaussian vector with a covariance matrix ${\bf K}$. How to compute
\begin{align}
E \left[ e^{-\|{\bf X}\|^2} \right]
\end{align}

The integral can easily be written as 
\begin{align}
&\int e^{-\|{\bf x}\|^2}  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^n det({\bf K})}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\bf x}^T{\bf K}^{-1}{\bf x}} d{\bf x}\\
&=\int e^{-{\bf x}^T {\bf x}}  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^n det({\bf K})}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\bf x}^T{\bf K}^{-1}{\bf x}} d{\bf x}\\
&= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^n det({\bf K})}} \int e^{-{\bf x}^T {\bf x}}   e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\bf x}^T{\bf K}^{-1}{\bf x}} d{\bf x}\\
&= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ (2 \pi)^n det({\bf K})}} \int    e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\bf x}^T( 2 {\bf I}+{\bf K}^{-1}){\bf x}} d{\bf x}
\end{align}

Now my question is how to integrate $\int    e^{-\frac{1}{2} {\bf x}^T( 2 {\bf I}+{\bf K}^{-1}){\bf x}} d{\bf x}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a positive definite matrix $\Sigma$, the probability density function association with the centered multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ in normalized to 1. Hence
$$
    \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot \Sigma^{-1} \cdot x\right) \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\left(2\pi\right)^n \cdot \det \Sigma} 
$$
The integral of interest has $\Sigma = \left( 2 \mathbb{I} + K^{-1} \right)^{-1}$, and it is obviously positive definite, since $K^{-1}$ is positive definite, and so is $2 \mathbb{I} + K^{-1}$.

Hence:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
   \mathbb{E}\left( \exp\left(-x^T x\right)\right) &=& \sqrt{\frac{\det \left(2 \mathbb{I} + K^{-1}\right)^{-1}}{\det K}} \cr &=& \sqrt{\frac{\det \left(\left(\mathbb{I} + 2 K \right) K^{-1} \right)^{-1} }{\det K}} \cr &=& \sqrt{ \det \left(\mathbb{I} + 2 K \right)^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det \left(\mathbb{I} + 2 K \right)}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: And $\det(M^{-1})=(\det(M))^{-1}$ and $\det(A)\det(B)=\det(AB)$ hence the last RHS is $$\frac1{\sqrt{\det(I+2K)}}$$